# Invoke Change Detection in Angular Reactive Forms AsyncValidator

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular Async Validators on my Reactive Form. Everything is working fine but the form is not refreshing with the error unless its repainted, so I'm trying to invoke the change detection inside the async validator. Problem is im not sure how to get a hang of the ChangeDetectorRef in the validator class. I'm getting a No Provider error when adding it in the constructor:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class EmailAliasValidator implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(
    private settingsService: SettingsService,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    /* private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,*/

    ) {}

  validate(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {

    return this.store.select(selectCurrentProperty).pipe(
        switchMap( property_id => {
            var id = property_id ? property_id : 0;
            return this.settingsService.uniqueEmailAlias(control.value, id)
        }),
        switchMap( isUnique => of(
            (isUnique == false ? { isDuplicateEmailAlias: true } : null )
          )
        ),
        take(1),
        delay(0),
        tap(() => /*this.cd.detectChanges()*/ )
    )
  }
}
```

And the component I basically do:

```
        this.form_general.addControl('email_alias', 
            new FormControl('', {
                validators: [Validators.required],
                asyncValidators: [this.uniqueEmailAlias.validate.bind(this.uniqueEmailAlias)],
                updateOn: 'blur',
            })
        );
```